# How to truncate less than 30 characters and delete in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with some rows of descriptions in a single column, what I am aiming is to get a formula that would truncate it upto certain character limit for example 30 characters and if the truncation stops at 30 character in the middle of the word then I remove that last word.

Here is the Formula that i am trying to make it work.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,30)-1)
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A none loop method

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<30,A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","}}}",30-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ",""))))-1))
```

[image]

Comment: You might need `A1&REPT(" ", 30)`  in one or more places for A1 strings that are less than 30 chars.

Answer (score 2):

Use AGGREGATE to locate the last space within the first 31 characters.

```
=LEFT(A2, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:$31)/(MID(A2&" ", ROW($1:$31), 1)=" "), 1) -1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Put in a module at VBA Editor (ALT+F11) -> Insert New Module.

When you past this code you can call it from any cell with "=NotTruncateWord(A1;30)"

There is some ajustments to do, because it is hard to know what is a Word (something after a space?), I ask because if someone write a 35 characteres string with no space, I will consider a word and remove all?

---

Public Function NotTruncateWord(Value, Limit)

```
LastSpaceBeforeLimit = 0
FirstSpaceAfterLimit = 9999

Phrase_Lenght = Len(Value)
If Phrase_Lenght > Limit Then

    For i = 1 To Phrase_Lenght
        check = Mid(Value, i, 1)
        If Asc(check) = 32 Then
           If i < Limit Then
              LastSpaceBeforeLimit = i
              ElseIf i < FirstSpaceAfterLimit Then
              FirstSpaceAfterLimit = i
           End If
        End If
    Next


    If LastSpaceBeforeLimit > 0 Then
       NotTruncateWord = Left(Value, LastSpaceBeforeLimit)
       Else
       NotTruncateWord = Left(Value, Limit)
    End If

    Else
    'no need to truncate
    NotTruncateWord = Value
End If
```

End Function